# SPFX - Webpart properties not appearing in search results

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-search

I have created spfx webpart which just displays the webpart property.
Following is the code.

[image]

[image]

"Hello" string is stored in my webpart property.

**Issue**:
When I try to search the webpart property content nothing appears in search results

but When I search "WebPartID+propertycontent", the page is displayed in the search results. AS you can see in following image the webpartid is appearing concatenated with the Webpart property.

[image]

Comment: Can you please update your previous post instead of opening multiple questions that in essence are the same?

Comment: @RobertLindgren, sure ill update my previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can help: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/integrate-web-part-properties-with-sharepoint.